# Elloquent ORM Model::with() returning NULL

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, inner-join

I have an issue retrieving objects using the `->with()` method of a Model object.

In my app, I have 4 tables (I write here what I think is the essential fields of my table, so ):

```
**Categories**:
id

**Subcategorie**
id
id_categorie

**UserSubcategorie**
id_user
id_subcategorie

**Lawyers**
user_id
```

I'm trying to get all the users for a given Categorie (which means all the users connected to all the categorie's subcategorie)

My request is as followed :

```
$categorie = LegalCategory::whereIn('id', $arrayCat)->with('legal_subcategories')->get();
foreach ($categorie as $k =>$cat){
    $selectedCat[$k]['categorie'] = $cat;
    $selectedCat[$k]['lawyers'] = 
        Lawyer::Join('lawyers_legal_subcategories', 'lawyers.user_id', '=', 'lawyers_legal_subcategories.user_id')
        ->with('lawyer_subcategories')
        ->whereIn('lawyers_legal_subcategories.legal_subcategory_id', $cat->legal_subcategories)
        ->get();                                                            
}
```

I'm getting the Lawyers correctly but when I look into `lawyer->legal_subcategories` , I have `NULL`

I don't understand why because when I try this :

```
Lawyer::orderBy('created_at')->take(4)->with('lawyer_subcategories')->get()
```

I have my subcategories in the Lawyer object.

Does someone has an idea about what the issue could be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line :

```
->whereIn('lawyers_legal_subcategories.legal_subcategory_id', $cat->legal_subcategories)
```

you need to pass array of IDs not all the subcategories !

```
$categorie = LegalCategory::whereIn('id', $arrayCat)
                            ->with('legal_subcategories')
                            ->get();
foreach ($categorie as $k =>$cat){
    $selectedCat[$k]['categorie'] = $cat;
    $selectedCat[$k]['lawyers'] = 
        Lawyer::Join('lawyers_legal_subcategories', 'lawyers.user_id', '=', 'lawyers_legal_subcategories.user_id')
        ->with('lawyer_subcategories')
        ->whereIn('lawyers_legal_subcategories.legal_subcategory_id', 
                    $cat->legal_subcategories->pluck('id'))
        ->get();                                                            
}
```

Comment: I still have some subcategories which are not retrieved but most of them are. So I guess you fixed the issue and I have a other one to find ^^ But thanks a lot. It worked fine for the most part !!

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how to use [has many through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) and [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). This will make you life easier.

On your case, you are making a lot of query, which will make your database suffer in the long run. Eager loading and Laravel eloquent provide a very efficient features to handle those kind of cases.

If you defined your model correctly, you retrieve all your needed data using with() method.